# setting global and using as argument

Tags: conditional-tags, globals

I've set a global variable in `functions.php` like so:

```
$cat_args = array('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3');
```

and tried to use it in a template file:

```
global $cat_args;
if is_cat($args):
//do stuff
endif;
```

The conditional returned false. If I `echo $cat_args` I get an array. Is there an extra step to passing it to the conditional / is what I'm trying to do possible? Thanks!

Comment: You did not set a global, and your syntax is wrong on the first line of the second code block, and it is a duplicate of : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/81584/21376

Comment: aside form the syntax error you pointed out, the code works.